# Using dojo dom.byId is not getting an element added programmatically

Tags: dom, dojo

I'm creating a dom element programatically using dojo and I can "see" it in the dom with its id, but when I attempt a dom.byId("myId") it returns null.

I have a similar [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crb66/jty4xwc7/) that is actually working (so it doesn't reproduce my problem, but it gives an idea of what I'm trying to do):  if you click the button (ignore the lack of styling) in the run output panel, it alerts the content of the element retrieved by dom.byId. But similar code within my dojo widget is not working.  Here's the code:

```
        var content = lang.replace(selectFilterTemplate, {
            "layer-id": layer.id,
            "layer-index": idx,
            "filter-name": filter.name
        });  // this gets template HTML code similar to what's in the HTML panel of the jsfiddle, only it has placeholder tags {} instead of literals, and the tags are replaced with the attributes of the layer, idx, and filter objects here

        // Use dojo dom-construct to create a div with the HTML from above
        var node = domConstruct.create("div", { "innerHTML": content });

        // put the new div into a dojo ContentPane
        var filterPanel = new ContentPane({
            "id": layer.id + "-filter-" + idx + "-panel",
            "content": node,
            "style": "width: 200px; float: left;"
        });

        // Get the dom element:
        var mstag = dom.byId(layer.id + "-filter-" + idx + "-ms-tag")
        // this is the same as the "var ms = dom.byId("IssuePoints-filter-1-ms-tag")" in the jsfiddle, but this one returns null.  If I view the contents of the 'node' variable in the browser debugging console at this point, I can see the <select> tag with the id I'm referencing.
```

Why would I be getting null in my dom.byId() if I can see that element in the dom in the debugging console?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the element is added to the dom at a later point. You may see it with the debugger but it is not yet available the moment you call byId().

In the code you posted you create the filterPanel element but you do not place it in the dom. I assume this happens at a later stage. In contrast, the jsfiddle places the Button element with placeAt() directly after constructing it.

Comment: Thanks pgianna.  putting a .plactAt(document.body) at the end of new ContentPane() did the trick for me.